# IWFile fix for c++ Builder XE?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, intraweb, delphi-xe, c++builder-xe

IWFile is broken in the current release of Rad Studio XE.  To fix it, Delphi users are asked to delete the UTF8ContentParser line. http://www.atozed.com/intraweb/blog/20100524.EN.aspx

c++ Builder has a line that #includes UTF8ContentParser.hpp.  Commenting out this line does not fix the issue.

Has anybody figured a way around this for C++Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And an answer to my own question....

<strike>11.0.18 was released today which fixes the IWFile issue.</strike>

Version 11.0.21 is the first public release available to XE owners.
Registration keys are available from atozed.com.
This version fixes the IWFile problem. (so did 11.0.18, but it was not available to XE owners)

Answer (score 1):

The blog says to remove the reference to UTF8ContentParser.pas from the **project source**, which means removing it from .dpr/.dpk files.  C++ `#include` statements, on the other hand, are produced by the Delphi compiler for entries in `uses` clauses inside of .pas files instead.  Which means there are .pas files that directly `use` the UTF8ContentParser unit when IntraWeb is compiled.  Commenting out `#include` statements in .hpp files will have no affect on that.  The references have to be removed from the original .pas files and then IntraWeb has to be recompiled with the changes.

Comment: And since I am using the intraweb that came with C++Builder, I guess I can't fix that issue.  sigh.  And its awful hard trying to get answers from the atozed people...they even list the latest release as 11.0.16 RC3, when the version shipped with Rad Studio is 11.0.17.

Comment: gbrandt, if your version of C++Builder comes with the Delphi source, as Professional-and-up versions do (I think, they come with most VCL source anyway) you can recompile it so you should be able to fix it.  C++Builder does compile Delphi code.

Answer (score 0):

Is the UTF8ContentParser.hpp perhaps included by other (.hpp or .cpp) files in other places as well?

Comment: The tag is c++builder, the file is .hpp  :-)   Low humour level after spending money and finding that something simply does not work.

Comment: IntraWeb / VCL for the Web is made and maintained by AtoZedSoftware. They have known for a couple of months now that this bugs exists (according to the blog post), so I recommend asking them what the status is (especially if the workaround doesn't work for C++Builder).